# Using different cakephp versions together

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to upgrade to 2.x application to 3.x. In my test server I upgraded my repository to CakePHP 3 changes. And it seems like application works well. Before releasing to all users I need to test new release with a minor group.

For example users from an IP range will try new version. Others will use old one.

My current folder is like this:

```
httpdocs/app/
        ...
        /app/webroot/index.php
        /css/
        /img/
        /lib/
        ...
        /new_version
```

Current DocumentRoot is `httpdocs/app/webroot`.
Cakephp 3's root folder is `httpdocs/new_version`

So what's the proper way to use both of them, withut changing DocumentRoot ? Should I change `/app/webroot/index.php`, check for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and include `/new_version/webroot/index.php`. Or copy pasting Cakephp 3's index.php to `httpdocs/app/webroot/index.php` ?

Or should I change `.htaccess` file and write a `RewriteCond` for `HTTP_HOST` ? OR is there a better way for this problem ?

Comment: Yeah not mixing them would be the solution to the problem. Just use a complete new folder and its own domain/subdomain.

Comment: Do you mean adding a subdomain to current domain and setting document root to new domain ?